# c#- How can I format an output so that a string always takes up 7 digits?

Tags: c#, string

```
string name1 = "John";
string name2 = "Alexander";

Console.WriteLine(??);

//desired output: 
John   Alexand
```

How can I format the strings so that they will always take up 7 spaces? I'm familiar with how to do this in C, but I cannot find a way to do it for C#.

Comment: `name1.PadRight(7).Substring(0, 7)`

Comment: [Paddiing strings in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, using C#6 interpolated strings, `$"{name1, -7} {name2, -7}"`

Comment: @Scott: formatting `$"{name1, -7}"` guarantees at *least* `7` positions, but not *exactly* `7` (i.e. `"Alexander"` will not be trimmed to `"Alexand"`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh true, good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PadRight` and `SubString`

```
var a = "James";
Console.WriteLine(a.PadRight(7, ' ').Substring(0, 7));
```

Comment: Love this, though you don't need to explicitly add the space character to `PadRight` (it's the default if you only specify one argument).

Answer (score 3):

Formatting like `$"{name, 7}"` ensures that the result will have length *at least* `7`; however, longer inputs will not be trimmed (i.e. `"Alexander"` will *not be trimmed* to `"Alexand"`).

We have to impement the logic *manually* and I suggest hiding it in an *extension method*:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
  public static string ToLength(this string source, int length) {
    if (length < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
    else if (length == 0)
      return "";
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
      return new string(' ', length);
    else if (source.Length < length)
      return source.PadRight(length);
    else
      return source.Substring(0, length); 
  }   
}
```

usage:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{name1.ToLength(7)} {name2.ToLength(7)}");
```

Comment: Nice extension method! :) Only thing I would say if I was being pedantic is that you don't need the `else if`s all the way down - you could just use `if` since you're `return`ing from each statement.

Comment: Agreed, very nice. But you could also remove the `length == 0` and `IsNullOrEmpty` checks, since it will never be `null` and the other conditions handle `string.Empty` as well as `length = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an extension method coupled with [`PadRight()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void Main() {
    string name1 = "John";
    string name2 = "Alexander";

    string FullName = name1.FixLeft(7) + name2.FixLeft(7);
    Console.WriteLine(FullName);
}

private static string FixLeft(this string TextInput, int DesiredLength) {
    if (TextInput.Length < DesiredLength) { return TextInput.PadRight(DesiredLength); }
    else { return TextInput.Substring(0,DesiredLength); }
}
```